# Options do not work inside zsh script

Tags: zsh

This does not seem to be a common problem, but i cannot get ZSH options to work within a ZSH script, e.g. `autocd`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

setopt autocd
my_directory
```

I just get 'command my_directory does not exist', which is what happens when that option isn't set. The fact that i don't get many search results for setting options inside scripts (and this question appears to be unique) suggests that i am missing some crucial piece of information that i have not seen yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code (from the latest `git` version, HEAD=36b8f83 on Nov 7 2014), in Src/exec.c, I see this on line 2854:

```
    char trycd = (isset(AUTOCD) && isset(SHINSTDIN) &&
                  (!redir || empty(redir)) && args && !empty(args) &&
                  !nextnode(firstnode(args)) && *(char *)peekfirst(args));
```

From this, it appears (although not documented that I can find) that the `SHINSTDIN` option must also be set for `AUTOCD` to work. However, you can't simply enable this option in a script (by adding `-s` to the shebang, for example), because then the shell running your script will not read commands from the script.

I don't know if preventing `AUTOCD` from working without `SHINSTDIN` is a bug, or if there is an undocumented reason why it must be true; this would be a good question for the zsh-workers mailing list.